# How can I find ComputedStyle elements in Nokogiri?

Tags: css, ruby, nokogiri

I'm using Ruby and Nokogiri to parse HTML documents, and I would like to select all nodes matching a CSS class, which I don't know in advance, but have the `display: none` style attribute.

**Example:**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p class="visibleTopics">Visible Topic Content</p>
    <p class="invisibleTopics">Invisible Topic Content</p>    
  </body
</html>
```

and in other file it's defined:

```
.invisibleTopic {
    display: none
}
```

I'd like to select the node with `invisibleTopics` content by its style `display: none`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Nokogiri won't see them unless you can capture the HTML after the nodes have been tweaked in the page. In that case, check out the [WATIR](http://watir.com/) project and gems.

Comment: Nice project, but unfortunately, I don't realize how could I integrate it with nokogiri. Thanks for the tip :-)

Comment: You integrate it by extracting the HTML that was rendered by the browser, which has been controlled by WATIR, and telling Nokogiri to parse that content. At that point you'll have the final HTML, as if you were using a browser to look at the page.

Comment: Why not grab all topics, visible or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokogiri doesn't compute styles. You need a browser for that. With Watir-Webdriver you would do:

```
browser.ps.reject{|p| p.visible?}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for the CSS attribute, look for the CSS class inside the tags:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<EOT
<html>
  <body>
    <p class="visibleTopics">Visible Topic Content</p>
    <p class="invisibleTopics">Invisible Topic Content</p>    
  </body
</html>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

doc.search('.invisibleTopics').each do |n|
  puts n.text
end
```

Which, when run, outputs:

```
Invisible Topic Content
```

Comment: The problem is I'm trying to figure out invisible elements, but i do not know the name of the class :-) Thanks!